# Better sort-by-newest for tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Once a site has reached a certain point, tag creation is no longer really necessary. Most of the new tags created on Physics.SE are crap (synonyms, localized, metatag, etc). Looking at the number of tag blacklist requests on MSO, it seems that SO has a similar problem.

Unfortunately, sorting tags by newest doesn't quite cut it. The newest sort doesn't show all tags, just a page or two of the recent ones.

Could we get full pagination here? There are a bunch of tags that probably ought to be burninated on (the nonexistant) page 3 onwards.

I think this will greatly help tag cleanup by helping us nip bad tags in the bud.

Comment: I believe it shows all the tags created in the last 14 days, there is no page size limit. For example, SO currently has 21 pages.

Comment: @anim well, that's not all the pages, right?

Comment: Why not just sort by popular and jump to the last page? They're ordered by number of questions tagged.

Comment: @animuson that doesn't help catching new tags as they come in. Note that I check every now and then, not too often. So the next pages do contain stuff i've missed.