# Give mods better tools to get rid of poor tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools

Currently, Ask Ubuntu is swamped by a lot of poor tags that just refuse to go away. The efforts to get rid of them by both the community and the moderators by manual retagging just doesn't cut it enough. As we try to eradicate them, they keep coming back. This drains the energy of the community members, who could spend this time better on doing more productive tasks on the site.

While blacklisting sounds like a good idea on paper, the amount of the paper work and red tape strongly discourages the moderators. From what I hear, it is, more often than not, a cumbersome task.

To list some of the tags:

- [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug) - Just killed this tag a couple of days ago.
- [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze)
- [slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/slow)
- [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash)

Hence, I request the devs to give the mods better tools than what is already available to them to delete poor tags without blacklisting them.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125812/give-moderators-the-ability-to-manage-blacklisted-tags and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-a-tag

Comment: Focus on deleting, not blacklisting. The SE team has already said no to allowing blacklisting; generally deleting is plenty good enough anyway

Comment: @BenBrocka How do you suggest this "deleting" tags be done? I have done plentiful retagging and I wouldn't want to do it again.

Comment: I'd made a [related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131590/better-sort-by-newest-for-tags) asking for better tag sort and search (for cleanup). Maybe you can incorporate that here?

Comment: @ManishEarth Good idea. But those tools won't be enough because you would still have to kill the tags by manual retagging. Nonetheless, they could be useful in maintaining the site.

Comment: I mean just... *delete* them. No permanent blacklist, just remove them from all existing questions with a click of a button (and a confirmation or whatever) for mods only

Comment: @BenBrocka I guess that is a reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

SO I know has the ['web' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web/info) that specifically says "DO NOT USE", and says what you should use instead. Also, after labeling don't use, you could then make all the related bad tags synonyms of one tag (so they don't show up directly).

But in the long run giving mods the ability to blacklist a tag (even if requiring many mod votes) would be useful.

Comment: I really doubt there are any _good_ tags that one can make such tags synonyms of.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles True, but you could make all the bad ones synonyms of each other (ex: `web` is a synonym of `www` which also says "DO NOT USE". You could even make a "Don't use tag" tag that uses they are all synonyms of so they don't show up)

Comment: @Kyomu Such practice is not welcome. You could replace a tag with [tag:please-do-not-use-it], but [tag:please-do-not-use-it] should be removed as soon as possible. Also, that would confuse the users who would see a tag replaced from another they didn't choose, and which seems useless.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Fair enough, just saying for now adding "DO NOT USE" to description would let people know not to use, and making similar bad ones synonyms would make them all say not to use.

Comment: @Kyomu You would think it should work, but in the site I moderate there are at least three tags whose description says something similar to "Do not use it. This tag is going to be removed." and still they are used in new questions. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno Alright, that's true. But it has always kept ME from using them on the occasion I consider it, so again, figure it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

What about letting folks flag tags like they can flag questions and comments?  Reasons can include:

- No questions use this tag
- Tag is superfluous (ex: [dictation](/questions/tagged/dictation) in [What causes the ios dictation keyboard to hide itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521505/what-causes-the-ios-dictation-keyboard-to-hide-itself)
- Tag ...

Comment: FWIW, unused tags are generally deleted after 24 hours.